# How to preserve user and group permissions using rsync?

Tags: rsync, nfs

I'm doing a NAS migration with mutltiprotocol shares. What rsync switches do I use to copy over UNIX user and group permissions? Also what are the standard switches usually used in an rsync copy?

Comment: Hello Steven. Why have you tagged this with [tag:nfs]?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try the `-a` switch, see: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: using EMCopy to migrate multiprotocol shares. What rsync switches can I use to run on shares after EMCopy has completed